# Handling ajax json object in Django - 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'read' error

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I am trying to parse json object in my Django view which has been passed through from client by ajax via post method.

JS:

`$.post ('/update_vendor_merchandise_types/', JSON.stringify(json_obj))`;

View:

```
def update_vendor_merchandise_types(request):
    print json_object
    # The output gives me  
    # QueryDict: <QueryDict: {u'[{"merchandise_id":"3"},{"merchandise_id":"4"}]': [u'']}>
    json_object = json.load(request.POST) # Error arises
pass
```

On the commented line `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'read' error` arises.
What am I doing wrong ?

Eventually, my goal is to get access to merchandise_id values. I try

```
d = request.POST.iteritems()
for key, value in d:
    print value
```

and expect something like

```
3 
4
```

Comment: You would do `json.load` to convert json format to a dict. Here, you have a dict you want to convert to `json`. You would be doing `json.dumps(request.POST.copy())`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `request.POST` is a dictionary which should contain any data you actually need, there isn't any point jsonifying it

Comment: I have edited the question. Please see the value of the json_object. I am trying to loop over it. Say, print all the merchandise_id and respective value values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.POST` is for form-encoded content. For JSON, you should access the plain body directly:

```
json_object = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: Daniel, I mark your answer as solution because your option translated json into python list which turned out easiest way to loop (d = json.loads(request.body)
    for x in d:
        print x['merchandise_id']). 
@Eduard, your suggested way also worked.

Comment: Daniel, can you see this question, please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586305/jquery-combining-form-serialize-and-stringified-json-object-in-data-paramete

Answer (score 4):

Why do you convert json_obj into string when sending it to server? I think you should do it in this way:

```
json_obj = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
$.post('/update_vendor_merchandise_types/', json_obj)
```

In this case on the server side you can access sent data in this way:

```
v1 = request.POST["key1"]
```

Comment: Eduard, actually, I would like the code of the loop to be as generic as possible, and I want to avoid addressing the json elements by their field names. Instead, my ultimate goal is to loop over it

Comment: may be your json_obj should look like this: `{"merchandise_ids": ["3", "4"]}`, in this case you can get on a server a list of merchandise ids by executing `ids = request.POST["merchandise_ids"]`